# Unity3D - Webplayer does not run in background (but setting is set...)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, clipboard, background-process

I want to create a simple application, which catches URL-Links in the clipboard (Ctrl + C) and opens them in a window (also closes the old, opened window).

I made a very simple script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

public class ClipboardWebpage : MonoBehaviour {



List<string> openedWindows = new List<string>();
void OpenNewPage(string url) {
    string name = "window";
    openedWindows.Add(name);
    Application.ExternalEval("var " + name  + " = window.open('" + url + "', 'title')");
}

void Start()
{
    Application.runInBackground = true;
}

string lastCheck = "";
void Update () {
    string clip = getClipboard();
    if (!lastCheck.Equals(clip))
    {
        lastCheck = clip;

        Uri uriResult;
        bool result = Uri.TryCreate(lastCheck, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult)
            && (uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps);
        if (result)
        {
            CloseAll();
            OpenNewPage(lastCheck);
        }
    }
}

void CloseAll()
{
    foreach (string name in openedWindows)
    {
        Application.ExternalEval(name + ".close()");
    }
}

string getClipboard()
{
    return GUIUtility.systemCopyBuffer;
}


void setClipboard(string value)
{
    GUIUtility.systemCopyBuffer = value;
}
}
```

The problem is, that the Web Player does not run this code, when it's not focused... (The run in background option is set in code and also in the player settings...)

Does anyone know, how to solve my problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Just checking that you have changed the webplayer Player Settings for Run In Background and not a different medium by mistake ?

Comment: I checked it now twice only to be sure. But indeed, the setting is set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a **bug** to me. I experinced this bug too with **5.1** and code below solved it for. Don't know what version you are using but give it a try.

Put the code in your **Update** function **NOT** in the **Start** function

```
if (!Application.runInBackground) {
             Application.runInBackground = true;
}
```

**EDIT 1**:
Mentioned that you are using **5.1.something**. That is a **bug** that has been fixed on **5.2.2** release.

**EDIT 2**:
The **solution** is to use **WebGL**.

`Application.ExternalCall()` and `Application.ExternalEval()` does not work with WebGL. WebGL requires that you make a plugin for it. The way you do it is different from the way you do it with WebPlayer.

**JavaScript Plugin:**

```
var MyPlugin = {
    HelloString: function(str)
    {
        window.alert(Pointer_stringify(str));
    },
    AddNumbers: function(x,y)
    {
        return x + y;
    },
};
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, MyPlugin);
```

Save as `Assets/Plugins/WebGL/MyPlugin.jslib`. The file extension must end with **.jslib**.

**To call from C#:**

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern void HelloString(string str);

[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern int AddNumbers(int x, int y);

void Start() {
    HelloString("This is a string.");

    int result = AddNumbers(5, 7);
    Debug.Log(result);
}
```

**NOTE:** Make sure to include `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html

Comment: Hey! Thanks for replying!
This code did not fix my problem, but I'm indeed using Unity 5.1... I will update it right now and let you know, what happend.

Comment: I just checked on Unity bug report system to verify and that bug is listed as fixed on 5.2.2 release. So yeah update Unity.

Comment: I did, but it did not fix the problem... My code works only, when I refocus the webplayer... Any other idea?

Comment: I I am downloading the unity WebGL plugin to test this myself. Is this all the code you have? Can you explain how the code work and how to use it here?

Comment: Of course: Yes this is all the code it needs. Attatch the script to the main cam of the scene. The script reads http or https links (for example the youtube link) and tries to open it in a new tab (via javascript: Application.ExternalEval(...) runs a command). so if you copy a link my programcode should open a new tab. (actual I am not sure why, but it does not work with the WebGL but the webplayer)

Comment: Wait a minute...Is this is WebPlayer not WebGL?  I read this wrong. WebPlayer is disconnected and will be removed on the 16th of this month which is next week Wednesday. Why not try this with Unity WebGL?  Tha'ts what I thought until I looked closer ...

Comment: how do i run javascript cmd in webgl?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105678/discussion-between-programmer-and-3dextended).